# How to get specific interface key in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, interface, typescript-generics

I have unem and an interface:

```
interface IPropertyPanelInfo {
    isVisible: boolean;
    //Позиция панели свойств. 0 - внизу 1- справа
    PositionPropertyPanel: PropertyPanelPosition;
    WidthPercentPropertyPanel: number;
    HeightPercentPropertyPanel: number;
}
export enum PropertyPanelPosition {
    Horizontal,
    Vertical
}
```

I want to create an object in which to implement a dynamic key record:
***panelPosition** may be 0 or 1 respectively*

```
const mutableObjectKey = panelPosition === PropertyPanelPosition.Horizontal ?
   'WidthPercentPropertyPanel'
   :
   'HeightPercentPropertyPanel';

const newObject = {
 [mutableObjectKey]:  20
}
```

the question is:
[image]
Is there a way to not hardcode this part using typescript?
and use the keys from the above interface?

Using *keyof*, I can get the interface keys(UNION), but I don’t understand how to get a unique key, is it possible to get a specific interface key by condition?

thanks in advance

Comment: you could only get the string literal *types* out of the interface. But there is no way to convert those into actual values.

Comment: I also need a string type, since the key of the object is a string
the question is different, how to correctly pull out the specific key of an object

Comment: do you have an object? It looks like you just have an `interface` currently.

Comment: Im talking about this object:
`const newObject = {[mutableObjectKey]:  20}`
with `keyof IPropertyPanelInfo` I can get union types of `interface` keys, but I need get only specific key for create `mutableObjectKey` , not union

Comment: Ok but how do you plan to select specific keys? Spelling them out completely seems to be something you want to avoid.